# Trying to run/compile my c++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation, visual-studio-2012

The project is a snake clone I made (ages ago). I made it in `VS2010.` Compiled and got everything working fine and dandy (ages ago).

Just come to wanting to run it again when I try to run the debug exe I get `"missing MSVCP100.dll".`

When i try to recompile (this time using vs2012) I get `multiple LNK2038 missmatch errors`saying

**error LNK2038**: `mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in AppStates.obj`

Any clue?

Comment: You need to "rebuild all" or whatever they call it. Basically compile all of the components from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

MSVCP100.dll is the C-Runtime for Visual Studio 2010. You'll need to import the project into VS2012 properly. Usually, when importing an old project into VS2012 you'll be ask if you want to convert it.

Comment: I've updated it to 2012 on opening it I was prompted, I pressed update, tryed to rebuild and i get the linker errors

Comment: Well, as a last resort, try to create a new project in VS2012 and include your old-content files. Not very nice, but it should work.